# Relation between sequences is the same as the relation between their limits

Tags: calculus, limits, inequality

Prove:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=A,\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=B,\forall n: a_n\le b_n \implies A\le B$$

I tried something like this:
$$A-\epsilon<a_n\le b_n<B+\epsilon$$
$$A-B<2\epsilon$$

Comment: Your idea is fine. If we assume $A>B$, we could let $\epsilon=\frac{A-B}2$ and arrive at a contradiction

Comment: I thought exactly of that, but there was no use of $a_n \le b_n$, and I could just as well do the opposite, and arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: But you *are* using $a_n\le b_n$ right there in $A-\epsilon<a_n\le b_n<B+\epsilon$.

Comment: Oh! Now I get it. It's quite a nice solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're absolutely right. Let's develop your idea:

By the definition of the limit and for arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ there's $N_1$ and $N_2$ such that:
$$\forall n\geq N_1: \ A-\epsilon<a_n$$
and
$$\forall n\geq N_2:\ b_n<B+\epsilon$$
so if $N=\max(N_1,N_2)$ we have:
$$\forall n\geq N:\ A-\epsilon<a_n\le b_n<B+\epsilon$$
and since $\epsilon$ is arbitary then
$$\forall \epsilon>0:\ A-B<2\epsilon$$
which means that $A-B$ is a lower bound for the set $\{2\epsilon, \forall \epsilon>0\}=\mathbb R_{>0}$ so $$A-B\leq 0=\inf \mathbb R_{>0}\iff A\leq B$$

Comment: I don't understand how you got to the last line.

Comment: $A-B<2\epsilon,\ \forall \epsilon>0$ means that $A-B$ is a lower bound for the set $\{2\epsilon, \forall \epsilon>0\}=\mathbb R_{>0}$ so $A-B\leq 0=\inf \mathbb R_{>0}$.

Comment: Very nice. Feel free to add that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What do you think about the sequence $c_n=b_n-a_n$ ?

Comment: Does $c_n\ge 0$ imply $\lim{c_n}\ge 0$?

Comment: Yes ! $c_n\rightarrow c$ and $c_n\geq 0$ imply $c\geq 0$ :